# TU Berlin eduroam - How to get Wireless LAN working with wpa_supplicant.conf and hashed password

Tags: wpa-supplicant, eduroam

I was struggling for awhile searching for a good `wpa_supplicant.conf` to
get access to the "eduroam" Wireless LAN network at the TU Berlin.

Since I know for sure, that it is not trivial and that the bash-script
actually saves your password in plain text I want to present the solution
to this problem in the answer.

So that anyone in the future can follow a real guide to get eduroam
working and not the fuzzy solution the tubIT presents you.

---

*Update - 21 10 2021: Will work with the "updated" auth process*

*Update - 04 03 2024: Will work after the AD changes*

---

The tubIT solution (namely [Configuration Assistant Tool](https://cat.eduroam.org/) or
[direct here](https://www.tubit.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/a40000000/tubIT/Software/eduroam-linux-TUB.sh) for the tubIT version) does not work properly (securely)
with `wpa_supplicant` nor is it build to do so.

`cat` was created with a (the) network manager
(`GNOME freedesktop NetworkManager`) in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question how to hash your password, so you can store it without running the danger of someone sneaking into your files to grab your TU password.

Since you don't want to be enrolled in some random course.

Jokes aside, to hash your password is a good idea and won't hurt you. To do so just type the following line into your terminal:

`echo -n "plaintext_password_here" | iconv -t utf16le | openssl dgst -md4 -provider legacy`

For Mac this would be

`echo -n "plaintext_password_here" | iconv -t UTF-16LE | openssl dgst -md4 -provider legacy`

This will output a hashed version of your password which we will use in the `wpa_supplicant.conf`

If you can't copy it from the terminal add  `| tee ~/hashed_pw` at the end to pipe the `stdout` to the file `hashed_pw` which lies in your home folder.

---

Now add the following network to your `wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
network={
    ssid="eduroam"
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    eap=PEAP
    anonymous_identity="wlan@tu-berlin.de"
    identity="YOUR_USERNAME@wlan.tu-berlin.de"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
    password=hash:YOUR_HASHED_PASSWORD
}
```

### The hashed password needs to be there plain without `""`!

Warning, you need to use `user@wlan.tu-berlin.de` not `user@tu-berlin.de`!

If I missed something or if there is any way to improve this guide, please comment or edit!

---

As a finishing touch an example:

```
network={
    ssid="eduroam"
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    eap=PEAP
    anonymous_identity="wlan@tu-berlin.de"
    identity="brolaf.s@wlan.tu-berlin.de"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
    password=hash:f77f16bc67fa1c9799055b7f5481f764
}
```

---

*Checked on 04 03 2024. Could change due to Cert changes in the future again*

---

Regarding the security of `md4`. Hashing your password with `md4` is sufficient to keep your password safe.

`md4` is only susceptible to collision attacks. This means if you sent a message and a hash to verify the message, you can change the message whilst still getting the same hash. At least as far as my knowledge goes.